# I can't install survminer package

Tags: r

I want to install surminer package but I see this code in R console

Warning in install.packages :
package ‘surminer’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-package

How can i install surminer package?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried installing via Github? (I'm guessing you mean `survminer`, not `surminer`)

```
library(devtools)

install_github('kassambara/survminer')
```

Comment: It is installed via Github